# Django database field overwritten by property?

Tags: python, django, properties, model, field

I would like to have a private field in my Model, and use it only under certain circumstances. But on the outside i would like to use it in a common way. For example my model is like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    __field = models.TextField(db_column = 'field')

    @property
    def field(self):
        if self.newSystem:
            return someOtherValue
        else:
            return __field
```

And now something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field='something')
```

raises an exception. Is there a possibility to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

yo can not use field in filter. But you can access to field like this

```
obj = MyModel.objects.all()[0]
obj.field
```

Comment: I know that. But I would like to use it in filter. I tried adding setter: @field.setter, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your confusion is here. You *cannot* use methods or properties in filters, no matter what. There is no way for the ORM to know that the property refers to an underlying db field. You can use the field  - ie `__field` here - directly, but not the property itself.